# How handle headphone button clicks in Java (computer)? No smarthphones related

Tags: java, audio, event-handling, headphones

There's a way to handle headphones button clicks in computer (not smartphone) with Java?

The usage is very similar to Android, which by pressing the button some event is fired.

There's not much info about this, then I thought a way to perform this could be interpret the bytes of the moment of the click, and based this, do something. This "could works" but I don't know if something changes by the button click in a computer, as happens in smartphones.

So is possible handle headphones clicks in computer?

Comment: I don't think so. Not with a regular 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: What makes this possible at mobile then? Custom and proper hardwares?

Comment: I believe so. See [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-play-pause-media-in-Windows-PC-by-earphone-button) for a related discussion.

Comment: Then depends of the jack type... Thanks for help. :(